# Can we use Lydia API or Lydia web sdk with React-Native

Tags: react-native

Lydia (easy paiement solution) propose **[Lydia API](https://homologation.lydia-app.com/doc/api/)** and **web** and **iOS** [SDKs](https://lydia-app.com/integration)

#### Does anyone has a proof that Lydia auth/paiement actions can work in a React-Native app?

What I actually think:

- Using the web sdk will maybe make the auth callbacks impossibles (like a web social auth on cordova => `cookies policy` errors)
- Using the `Lydia API` using `fetch` is surelly ok, but without SDK the experience will be limited to create/read data from api.

---

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lydia tech lead here.

All SDKs you can find are just a quick and easy integration of the API : they are mainly distributed to not tech people. Using Lydia to make a payment is easy just one cURL.

Actually, there is no auth required for a payment through Lydia : the only thing you need is a phone number or an email address.

The API will return a link you can redirect the user to. If he has the app, it will open it for a on click payment. If he doesn't he will land on a credit card form. In both case, after the payment, he will redirected to an URL you gave when sending the payment request (meanwhile the payment confirmation will be done by a server to server call).